# Better resolution for 12x12" printing of pics

Tags: resolution

I downloaded some daisy pics which had poor resolution(320x480) for my needs( 12x12 inch print). I tried increasing the resolution with  Windows' paint, but ended up with a blurred image. After reading some previous responses to improving resolution, it appears that I can not improve my image resolution to what Costco recommends for printing. So, where can I find pics that would support the resolution size that Costco recommends for a 12x12 inch print?## Heading ## Costco recommends a minimum of 1265x 1610 and premium is 3300x4200. I am using Windows 8.

Comment: You need to find higher-resolution images. This may mean contacting the image owners.

Comment: Use google to find some daisy pics that have a higher resolution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually specify resolution of images with google search!

1. Go to images.google.com
2. Input your search
3. Select 'Search Tools'
   [image]
4. Go to the 'Size' drop down and specify your size
   [image]

Make sure to give proper attribution and/or make sure the image is in public domain!

Comment: Note also, that its possible to drag your current picture to the google search bar in step 3. Drop the pic itself on the search bar.

Comment: @Tyson - Changing just the resolution of an existing low quality image will make a new image at that resolution that is low quality.

Comment: @Ramhound if you drag an existing low quality image and drop it on google search it will offer other resolutions of the same image (if they exist) and it will also offer visually similar images.

Comment: I missed understood the suggest then.